# Is it possible to capture the username in a Google Chrome extension in a platform independent way?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-platform, google-chrome-extension, platform-independent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the windows user name using javascript in google chrome browser for google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335342/how-to-get-the-windows-user-name-using-javascript-in-google-chrome-browser-for-g)

Does Google Chrome support this in a native way? If not, is there a good workaround?

Comment: @serg: The OS username or anything to identify the user uniquely will do.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [NPAPI Plugins](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html)
And according to google, Code running in an NPAPI plugin has the full permissions of the current user and is not sandboxed or shielded from malicious input by Google Chrome in any way.